# How solve the dimension input for a convolutional model?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, input, conv-neural-network

I have a little problem with the dimensions input for a ConvNet. First of all i created two np.array of png images, one for patient's data and one for maskes.
Then i resized them in this way:

```
print('patient_train shape:', np.array(patient_train).shape)
# Then resize the dimension of the np.array
patient_train.resize((sample_width, sample_height, 1))
print('patient_train resize:', np.array(patient_train).shape)
```

Specular for the mask's array called patient_mask_train. First question, is it correct or is the function wrong? The result is this:

```
patient_train shape: (512, 512, 3)
patient_train after resize: (128, 128, 1)
patient_mask_train shape: (512, 512, 3)
patient_mask_train after resize: (128, 128, 1)
```

Then the get_model function is defined:

```
def get_model(optimizer, loss_metric, metrics, lr=1e-3):
    inputs = Input((sample_width, sample_height, 1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv3)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.3)(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.3)(pool4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])

    # working with dice and adam
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(lr=lr), loss=loss_metric, metrics=metrics)


    return model
```

The calling is:

```
model.fit(patient_train, patient_mask_train, batch_size=int(len(patient_train)/4), 
          epochs=250, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[model_checkpoint, model_reset])
```

But it gives me

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_5'), name='input_5', description="created by layer 'input_5'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 128, 1, 1).
```

And

```
ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [?,16,2] and [?,16,1]. for '{{node model_4/concatenate_16/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model_4/conv2d_transpose_16/BiasAdd, model_4/conv2d_83/Relu, model_4/concatenate_16/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,16,2,256], [?,16,1,256], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <3>.
```

How can i solve this problem? Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Just before you call `model.fit()` what are the dimension of `patient_train` and `patient_mask_train`?

Comment: patient_train shape: (512, 512, 3) - patient_train resize: (128, 128, 1) - patient_mask_train shape: (512, 512, 3) - patient_mask_train resize: (128, 128, 1) - if ndim function is used patient_train dim: 3 and patient_mask_train dim: 3 -  if size function is used patient_train size: 16384 - patient_mask_train size: 16384

Comment: Hmm.. so what about the dataset size (total num of images)? Since you specify `batch_size`, your inputs must iterate over the entire dataset (num_images). In case, if the input size for `patient_train` and `patient_mask_train` are (128, 128, 1) then it is wrong.  Your inputs need to be 4-dimensional: (num_images, 128, 128, 1).

Comment: Your model in OK with input `(None,128,128,1)`. But as the error states, you have passed input with shape `(None,128,1,1)`.

Comment: The total number of images for each folder is 129 images. I tried to modify the function in this way: `patient_train.resize((129, sample_width, sample_height, 1))`  where sample_widt = 128 and sample_height = 128. It results `patient_train resize: (129, 128, 128, 1)` and  `numpy=
array([[[[0.],
         [0.],
         [0.],
         ... ` , so it's all 0